# How to copy android partition and recover deleted data?

Tags: android, filesystems, adb, recovery, file-recovery

I used this command to copy entire internal storage partition sda as sda.img (24.6 GB).

```
adb pull /dev/block/sda sda.img
```

Then I used OSFMount on Windows and mounted as read-only drive, but it shows

```
Location is not available
E:\ is not accessible.
The parameter is incorrect.
```

I opened it with 7-Zip and Winrar, but it shows that it can't be opened as archive.

These are the partitions located on my phone, I assumed sda is internal storage and the size of the img is around the same size of what I see in file managers (23.84 internal, 3.94 GB root).

```
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root         36 1970-01-06 10:24 bootdevice -> /dev/block/platform/soc/624000.ufshc
0 drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root       1420 1970-01-06 10:24 by-name
0 brw------- 1 root   root     7,   0 1970-01-06 10:24 loop0
0 brw------- 1 root   root     7,   8 1970-01-06 10:24 loop1
0 brw------- 1 root   root     7,  16 1970-01-06 10:24 loop2
0 brw------- 1 root   root     7,  24 1970-01-06 10:24 loop3
0 brw------- 1 root   root     7,  32 1970-01-06 10:24 loop4
0 brw------- 1 root   root     7,  40 1970-01-06 10:24 loop5
0 brw------- 1 root   root     7,  48 1970-01-06 10:24 loop6
0 brw------- 1 root   root     7,  56 1970-01-06 10:24 loop7
0 drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root         60 1970-01-06 10:24 platform
0 brw------- 1 root   root     1,   0 1970-01-06 10:24 ram0
0 brw------- 1 root   root     1,   1 1970-01-06 10:24 ram1
0 brw------- 1 root   root     1,  10 1970-01-06 10:24 ram10
0 brw------- 1 root   root     1,  11 1970-01-06 10:24 ram11
0 brw------- 1 root   root     1,  12 1970-01-06 10:24 ram12
0 brw------- 1 root   root     1,  13 1970-01-06 10:24 ram13
0 brw------- 1 root   root     1,  14 1970-01-06 10:24 ram14
0 brw------- 1 root   root     1,  15 1970-01-06 10:24 ram15
0 brw------- 1 root   root     1,   2 1970-01-06 10:24 ram2
0 brw------- 1 root   root     1,   3 1970-01-06 10:24 ram3
0 brw------- 1 root   root     1,   4 1970-01-06 10:24 ram4
0 brw------- 1 root   root     1,   5 1970-01-06 10:24 ram5
0 brw------- 1 root   root     1,   6 1970-01-06 10:24 ram6
0 brw------- 1 root   root     1,   7 1970-01-06 10:24 ram7
0 brw------- 1 root   root     1,   8 1970-01-06 10:24 ram8
0 brw------- 1 root   root     1,   9 1970-01-06 10:24 ram9
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,   0 1970-01-06 10:24 sda
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,   1 1970-01-06 10:24 sda1
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  10 1970-01-06 10:24 sda10
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,   2 1970-01-06 10:24 sda2
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,   3 1970-01-06 10:24 sda3
0 brw-rw---- 1 system system   8,   4 1970-01-06 10:24 sda4
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,   5 1970-01-06 10:24 sda5
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,   6 1970-01-06 10:24 sda6
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,   7 1970-01-06 10:24 sda7
0 brw------- 1 system system   8,   8 2021-08-30 00:55 sda8
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,   9 1970-01-06 10:24 sda9
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  16 1970-01-06 10:24 sdb
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  17 1970-01-06 10:24 sdb1
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  32 1970-01-06 10:24 sdc
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  33 1970-01-06 10:24 sdc1
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  48 1970-01-06 10:24 sdd
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  49 1970-01-06 10:24 sdd1
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  50 1970-01-06 10:24 sdd2
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  51 1970-01-06 10:24 sdd3
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  64 1970-01-06 10:24 sde
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  65 1970-01-06 10:24 sde1
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  74 1970-01-06 10:24 sde10
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  75 1970-01-06 10:24 sde11
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  76 1970-01-06 10:24 sde12
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  77 1970-01-06 10:24 sde13
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  78 1970-01-06 10:24 sde14
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  79 1970-01-06 10:24 sde15
0 brw------- 1 root   root   259,   0 1970-01-06 10:24 sde16
0 brw------- 1 root   root   259,   1 1970-01-06 10:24 sde17
0 brw------- 1 root   root   259,   2 1970-01-06 10:24 sde18
0 brw------- 1 root   root   259,   3 1970-01-06 10:24 sde19
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  66 1970-01-06 10:24 sde2
0 brw------- 1 root   root   259,   4 1970-01-06 10:24 sde20
0 brw-r----- 1 system system 259,   5 1970-01-06 10:24 sde21
0 brw------- 1 root   root   259,   6 1970-01-06 10:24 sde22
0 brw------- 1 root   root   259,   7 1970-01-06 10:24 sde23
0 brw------- 1 root   root   259,   8 1970-01-06 10:24 sde24
0 brw------- 1 root   root   259,   9 1970-01-06 10:24 sde25
0 brw------- 1 root   root   259,  10 1970-01-06 10:24 sde26
0 brw------- 1 root   root   259,  11 1970-01-06 10:24 sde27
0 brw------- 1 root   root   259,  12 1970-01-06 10:24 sde28
0 brw------- 1 root   root   259,  13 1970-01-06 10:24 sde29
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  67 1970-01-06 10:24 sde3
0 brw------- 1 root   root   259,  14 1970-01-06 10:24 sde30
0 brw------- 1 root   root   259,  15 1970-01-06 10:24 sde31
0 brw------- 1 root   root   259,  16 1970-01-06 10:24 sde32
0 brw------- 1 root   root   259,  17 1970-01-06 10:24 sde33
0 brw------- 1 root   root   259,  18 1970-01-06 10:24 sde34
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  68 1970-01-06 10:24 sde4
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  69 1970-01-06 10:24 sde5
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  70 1970-01-06 10:24 sde6
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  71 1970-01-06 10:24 sde7
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  72 1970-01-06 10:24 sde8
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  73 1970-01-06 10:24 sde9
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  80 1970-01-06 10:24 sdf
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  81 2021-08-30 09:48 sdf1
0 brw-rw---- 1 system system   8,  90 1970-01-06 10:24 sdf10
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  91 1970-01-06 10:24 sdf11
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  92 1970-01-06 10:24 sdf12
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  93 1970-01-06 10:24 sdf13
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  94 1970-01-06 10:24 sdf14
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  82 1970-01-06 10:24 sdf2
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  83 2021-08-30 09:44 sdf3
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  84 1970-01-06 10:24 sdf4
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  85 1970-01-06 10:24 sdf5
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  86 1970-01-06 10:24 sdf6
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  87 1970-01-06 10:24 sdf7
0 brw------- 1 root   root     8,  88 1970-01-06 10:24 sdf8
0 brw-rw---- 1 system system   8,  89 1970-01-06 10:24 sdf9
0 drwx------ 2 root   root         40 1970-01-06 10:24 vold
0 brw------- 1 root   root   254,   0 2021-08-30 00:55 zram0
```

How can I recover this internal storage partition and mount it to use for example Recuva or Active@ Undelete on Windows to recover deleted files?

Answer (score 0):

Your partition image runs with a Unix like filesystem, something like ext3 or ext4.
You could mount the image under linux.

Using only windows, you should download [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and instruct it to open the file. From there, you should be able to search for a valid filesystem then browse the content, unless your sda isn't the root, which given the size, should be.

Comment: I tried opening it using testdisk, it detected it as intel partition table type, but still having problem analyzing the img file.
>Warning: Bad ending head (CHS and LBA don't match)                                                                      >No partition is bootable

Also when listing files, it shows "No file found, filesystem may be damaged."